# error : exception : Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation. temp was 0xDDDDDDDD

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am a beginner and am working on Linked list. I am trying to make a program which adds elements to the list, updates the list, dislays it and deletes it.I am getting an exception : read access violation.  temp was 0xDDDDDDDD.
I think there is some problem with display() function. The debugger also does shows the same.

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "Node.h"
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    Node::Node() //constructor
    {
        head = NULL;
    }

    Node::~Node()    //destructor
    {
    }

    void Node::addFirstNode(int n)    //adding the first element in the list
    {
        node *temp = new node;
        temp->data = n;
        temp->next = NULL;
        head = temp;    
    }

    void Node :: addLast(int n)    //Adding elements at the end of the list
    {
        node *last = new node;
        last->data = n;
        last->next = NULL;
        node *temp = new node;

        temp = head;        
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }       
        temp->next = last;  
    }

    void Node::display()      //Displaying the list
    {
        node *temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            cout<<temp->data;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }


//the main function:

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Node a;
    a.addFirstNode(101);    //Calling function : addFirstNode

    a.addLast(102);         //Calling function : addLast

    a.addLast(103);       //Calling function : addLast

    a.addLast(104);       //Calling function : addLast

    a.display();         //Calling function : display
    return 0;
}
```

The Node.h file is as below:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};

class Node
{
private :
    node *head;

public:
    Node();
    ~Node();
    void addFirstNode(int n);
    void addLast(int n);    
    void display(); 
};
```

Comment: You should look at the call stack to find out why and where it's happening

Comment: Note: you have a memory leak at `node *temp = new node;` You allocate an object and then just lean it by doing `temp = head` right after. Also show the code calling this so we know exactly what you’re doing

Comment: In `Node::addFirst()`, `temp->next = NULL;` should be `temp->next = head;`

Comment: But I want the head to be equal to temp, and hence I have first set the data and the next of  the temp node and then equated the head  to temp node. Should this not work?

Comment: What does `node.h` look like ?

Comment: Interesting fun fact: Wiki has accumulated a great list of [magic numbers used by development tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_debug_values). When you see an unusually regular number like 0xDDDDDDDD, look it up. It often means something.

Answer (score 0):

You should rename `Node` to better describe what it is, e.g. `List`.

In `Node::addFirst()`, replace `temp->next = NULL;` with `temp->next = head;`  You don't want to throw away your list every time you add a `Node` to the beginning of it.

In `Node::addLast()`, replace `node *temp = new node;` with `node *temp = head;` You don't want to leak memory every time you add a `Node` to the end of it.